# What is the sharpest aperture for Canon 550d with Sigma 8mm?

Tags: depth-of-field

I usually use F/8 and a manual zoom at 1m. What configuration should I use to assure both objects that are far away(10m) and objects that are close(1-2m) are sharp

Comment: I would try a depth of field calculator such as the one here: http://www.dofmaster.com/dofjs.html
It should be pretty easy to get a wide depth of field if you really do have a lens at 8mm.

Comment: ^^^ stick this as an answer, it's a nice simple solution.
Also a great lens, love mine ;)

Comment: Note that the sharpest aperture and the aperture which provides the greatest depth of field are different.

Comment: what is the diffrece? I am interested in a photo where everything is sharp, nothing blurred

Answer (score 5):

For achieving maximum sharpness, your aperture must be

- stopped down about a stop or two from maximum aperture for optimal optical resolution;
- stopped down enough so that depth of field would be sufficient;
- open enough so that shutter time would not be long enough to introduce camera shake and motion of subject would not be visible;
- open enough so that diffraction would not cause blurriness.

According to MTF50 chart in [review by Photodo](http://www.photodo.com/topic_174.html), the lens has best optical resolution from about f/4.5 to about f/6.3.

Since [diffraction limit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/what-is-a-diffraction-limit) for Canon 550d is about f/6.8, so the smallest selectable aperture (for  largest DOF) without diffraction is also f/6.3.

If using f/6.3 results in a shutter speed too low to avoid camera or subject motion, you might get a sharper result using a larger aperture or higher ISO. Or you might have to close down further if depth of field is insufficient. At f/6.3, hyperfocal distance is half a meter, so the distances you mentioned in your question are well within focus.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where I would **strongly** recommend performing an experiment for yourself.  With 1/3 stops, the lens only supports 17 aperture settings.  Set up a tripod, manually focus the lens, put the camera in Av mode, [cover the viewfinder](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/700/should-i-use-the-rubber-viewfinder-cover), use a remote release cable, and take a picture at each aperture; it should only take about 5 minutes.  Then you can examine the results at whatever zoom level you want on your computer monitor.

You may well find that there's a range of apertures that have indistinguishable sharpness, which would give you more freedom in the future!  You'll also learn a little bit more about the characteristics of your lens+camera combination, like any exposure shifts at different apertures.

Finally, if the results *aren't* sharp enough for you, you may want to add light or post-process the photos to increase the sharpness of your subjects.